# MySQL on node.js syntax error I can't figure out

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have this function to register a new user in the DB:

```
this.registerUser = function(username,password,name,picture){
client.query('INSERT INTO' + USER +'SET username=?,passsword=?,name=?,picture=?',[username,password,name,picture],
function(err){
if(err){
    throw err;
  }
 });
}
```

This is the line used to call the function from another module:

```
var data = new db.dataBase('root','root');
data.registerUser("a","a","a","a");
```

and this is the MySQL table:

```
client.query(
'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS '+USER+
'(username VARCHAR(255), '+
'password VARCHAR(255), '+
'name VARCHAR(255), '+
'picture VARCHAR(255), '+
'PRIMARY KEY(username))'
);
```

and for some unknown reason(for me) I am getting this error:

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'username='a',password='a',name='a',picture='a'' at line 1
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong here, please help.

Thank You!

Comment: What's the value of `USER`? Can you print the query itself?

Comment: @DorShemer USER is the name of the table, and i cant print anything, it just gives me the error msg and stops the program

Comment: What's the value of `USER`, and were you careful with whitespace in your question? Because it looks like your query will concatenate as `INSERT INTOmytablenameSET username...`.

Comment: @Itzik984 please show us the SQL query itself

Comment: @DorShemer the query is written above: client.query('INSERT INTO' + USER.... anything else needed?

Comment: @Itzik984 you are making it very difficult to help you. When asked for the query, the idea was that you show us the output of the string 'INSERT INTO'+USER+'SET ...', so we can tell if something is wrong

Comment: @DorShemer the problem was the spaces... thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its problem with spaces,:

```
//add space after INTO and before SET
client.query('INSERT INTO ' + USER +' SET username=?,passsword=?,name=?,picture=?',[username,password,name,picture],
```

Hope it helps

Comment: glad to know it worked, should be careful of the DAMN spaces dude.. :)

Comment: @Itzik984 If you build your query in a string e.g. `var query = 'SELECT ...';` you can use `console.log(query)` to verify that it's valid SQL.